# Regex for allowing numbers without leading and ending 0

Tags: regex

I want except some numbers in different syntax and I am trying to find the best Regex for this task/match.

First some valid numbers:

```
0.01
0.2
0.38
45
165.6
52732.08
999999999.99
```

And here some invalid numbers:

```
.01
.2
.50
.85
45.
45.0
45.00
00045.0
124.60
000124.60
124,6
000053853.01
999.999.999,99
999999999,99
```

After several tests I have created the following Regex:

```
^[1-9]?\d{1,9}\.?\d{1,2}(?<!0)$
```

But I always struggling on the number: `000058723.01`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Which language you're using?

Comment: Your requirement is not quite clear in the question, I guess you do not want to match numbers ending with `0` if this zero is in the decimal part, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accept four kinds of input:

1. A number with no decimal places and without leading zeroes: `[1-9]\d*`
2. Zero followed by a dot followed by digits (without trailing zeroes): `0\.\d*[1-9]`
3. A decimal number without leading or trailing zeroes: `[1-9]\d*\.\d*[1-9]`
4. Zero: `0`

Putting the four together:

```
^([1-9]\d*|0\.\d*[1-9]|[1-9]\d*\.\d*[1-9]|0)$
```

Comment: Can be compacted to `^(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d*[1-9])?$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!0+\d)\d+(?:\.(?![1-9]*0+$)\d{1,2})?$
```

Or:

```
^(?:0+|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.(?![1-9]*0+$)\d{1,2})?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZ2tK7/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
^((?:0|[1-9]+)(?:\.(?:\d+?[1-9]|[1-9]))?)$
```

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/XKkATHqAUE)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed version of your regex:

```
^(?!0{2,})\d+(?:\.\d{1,2}(?<!0))?$
```

Here, initial 2 or more zeros are not allowed with the lookahead `(?!0{2,})`, and the decimal part is made optional within a non-capturing group `(?:\.\d{1,2}(?<!0))?`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iB9sX6/2)

In case you do not want to match `0`, you can exclude this in the negative lookahead:

```
^(?!0{2,}|0$)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2}(?<!0))?$
          ^^
```

See [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/iB9sX6/3)

Answer (score 0):

A number with optional decimals is composed from two pieces: the integer part and the optional decimal part that starts with a dot.

The integer part is either zero (`0`) or a sequence of digits that start with `1..9` (no `0`) and can continue with zero or more digits:

```
0|[1-9][0-9]*
```

If you need to impose an upper limit on the integer part's length then replace `*` with `{,n}` where `n` is the maximum allowed length minus 1.

The decimal part starts with a dot (`.`) followed by zero or more digits and followed by one of `1..9` (no `0` allowed at the end).

The expression is:

```
\.[0-9]*[1-9]
```

Now let's combine them:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.[0-9]*[1-9])?$
```

What I added when I joined the pieces:

- `^` - match the start of the string; without this the `regex` matches `45.0` from `00045.0`;
- parentheses around the integer part because of the lower precedence of `|`;
- parentheses around the decimal part, followed by `?` to signal the entire decimal part is optional;
- `$` - match the end of the string to avoid matching `124.6` from `124.60`.

#### Remarks

The above `regex` was designed to match your examples. However, please notice that most programming languages allow most or all of the numbers you put in the "invalid" section and use a dot (`.`) as decimal separator. And many languages provide library functions that are able to parse the numbers that use a comma (`,`) as decimal separator.

Numbers without integer part (`.85`), without digits after the dot (`45.`) ore with trailing zeros (`45.0`) are valid and are interpreted without ambiguity.

The only troublemaker is the leading zero (`00045.0`). For integer numbers, most of the times it is a signal that the number is represented in base `8` while for real numbers it is simply ignored.